# Will a literal string assignment call the String constructor like this?

Tags: c#, string, constructor

Out of curiosity, if I call:

```
 string txt = "text";
```

Will it call this, behind the scenes?

```
 string txt = new String("text".ToCharArray())?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not.  This code will translate directly into an IL `stloc` command.  It will essentially compile to the following

```
ldstr "text"
stloc.0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
string txt1 = "text";
```

loads the string `"text"` from the [intern pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) and stores it as reference in the `txt1` variable.

So, for example, if you have

```
string txt2 = "text"; 
string txt3 = "text";
```

then `ReferenceEquals(txt2, txt3) == true`, because both variables reference the same string object in the intern pool.

The [String Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx) creates a new, non-interned string object.

```
string txt4 = new String("text".ToCharArray());
```

So `ReferenceEquals(txt1, txt4) == false`.

There is one exception: `new String(new char[0])` returns the reference to the `""` string object in the intern pool.

Answer (score -1):

i doubt it - why would it

But why not look for yourself, run ildasm and see what code is generated